# pgfplotstable: Use predefined numbers to access table positions / styles (syntax-problem, bug?)

Tags: pgfplotstable, expansion

Why does

```
\def\y{0}
\def\x{1}

every row no \y column no \x/.style={  
/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{pink}}{},      },
```

not work?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma, header=false}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
a, b, c, d, e, f
h, i, j, k, l, m
n, o, p, q, r, s
t, u, v, w, x, y
}\mytable


\begin{document}
\section{Works}
\def\N{1}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
every row no \N/.style={before row={\rowcolor{orange}}},
]{\mytable}

\section{Works not}
\def\y{0}
\def\x{1}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
% Works
%every row no 0 column no 1/.style={  
%/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{pink}}{},      },
% Works not: 
every row no \y column no \x/.style={  
/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{pink}}{},      },
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In key `every row no \y column no \x`, the space character just after `\y` is ignored, hence the key looks like `every row no 0column no 1` and is never executed.

To keep that space, either `\def\y{0 }` or `every row no \y\space column no \x` works.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It's kind of buggy or not?

Comment: @cis It's the expected behavior. A space character just after the control sequence is always ignored, for example compare "text \LaTeX text" and "text \LaTeX{} text".